# Rails 3.2.6: Deleting all data and public files from production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I have successfully managed to set up a VPS production server (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS) from the excellent [Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps). It's an "internal" server (not live yet), so I've been building my app locally and doing a `cap deploy` at regular intervals to check that things are running smoothly.

However, what I'd like to do now is delete all records on the production server (as I've just been testing stuff) - that is, to start with a completely empty database for when the site actually goes live to the public.

Obviously, I can do this locally by running something like `rake db:reset`, but how do I do this on the production server? Should I be adding some code to my `deploy.rb` file?

I'm a bit of a noob at this, but I've been unable to find anything via a Google search.

** EDIT ** Oh, and obviously this is a one-off - once things go live, I'll remove any code which deletes records!

Comment: A side note, you should update your rails version ASAP, hopefully before going live to anyone due to a known security vulnerability: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/1/8/Rails-3-2-11-3-1-10-3-0-19-and-2-3-15-have-been-released/

Comment: Thanks! I'd heard of that vulnerability so, yes, I agree I should update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ssh into the server and run any `rake` command from the application directory. You could create a Capistrano task just to run this one rake task, but since this task is obscenely dangerous with any real system I would not recommend it. The last thing you would want is to accidentally run it.

Comment: SSHing in to the application directory (apps/myapp/) doesn't work - it gives the following error: "rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)"

Comment: Sound like you are in the wrong directory. Look for a `current` directory. Capistrano keeps around old versions and symlinks the current version there. The Rails directory should contain a `Rakefile`.

Comment: Ah! I had to be in the `current` directory, and then I had to use `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:reset`